# New database connection after build application

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework, playframework-2.3

I have very strange problem with creating JPA Entity Manager after every rebuild application. Now in application I have static class for get EntityManger from DAO classes:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import play.db.jpa.JPA;

public class AppEntityManager {

    private static EntityManager em = JPA.em("default");

    public static EntityManager getInstance() {     
        return em;
    }

}
```

Example how I use this is class:

```
public static User getUserByUsername(String username) {
        Query query = AppEntityManager.getInstance().createQuery("select u from User u where u.username = :username", User.class);
        query.setParameter("username", username);
        try {
            return (User) query.getSingleResult();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }
```

The first time you create a 5 connections to the database. But after recompiling application each time is added on the same connection. I can not understand why and how to fix it. Please show an example of how to use JPA + Hibernate correctly.

Comment: so are you actually closing these EntityManagers anywhere? because you have to sooner or later. Or is it using a single EntityManager for all use ? (single threaded?)

Comment: No. I never close EntityManager. Maybe I did not use it correctly. I would be glad if prompt best practices

Comment: depends what "JPA.em(...)" does. Suggest you look at its javadocs